# Limit autocomplete scope in Eclipse/CCS

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I am working in Eclipse, specifically Code Composer Studio. When activating Content Assist (autocomplete), I get a list of results throughout the entire project. This is starting to reduce the efficiency of autocomplete, as many similar results will show up and I have to look through and possibly scroll to find the correct one.

I really only need results limited to the current scope. Is there a way to limit the search to the current scope?